# Image duplication at react-carousel-minimal library after get images from API and insert into Carousel

Tags: reactjs

I'm coding with React class component verison 17 and I'm using the [react-carousel-minimal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-carousel-minimal/v/1.4.1) library in order to build the carousel.

I'm calling the API on constructor method and I'm getting two images from this API, like this below:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  autobind(this);

  this.state = {
    dataBanner : []
  };
  api.selectList(`/banner`).then((res) => {
    let resultBanner = [];
    if (res.result?.length) {
      for (const dataBuffer of res.result) {
        const imgBase64 = this.convertBufferToBase64(dataBuffer?.data);
        resultBanner.push(imgBase64);
      }
    }
    this.setState({ dataBanner : resultBanner });
  });
}
```

On render method, I get the dataBanner state and I insert it in dataBanner variable, like this below:

```
render() {
  const { dataBanner } = this.state;
```

Finally, on the return I call the carousel library:

```
return(
          <Carousel
            data={dataBanner}
            time={5000}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            automatic={true}
            dots={true}
            pauseIconColor="white"
            pauseIconSize="0px"
            slideBackgroundColor="darkgrey"
            slideImageFit="cover"
            captionStyle={{
              position: 'absolute',
              padding: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'
            }}
          />
 );
```

The problem is that these two images are appearing at the first slide. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

How can I show each image at a single slide?
Thanks.